# Python code to translate Chinese letters to English from a Dataframe

Tags: python, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I am trying to translate a column which contains names of Chinese company and I would like to translate it to the actual English word and not the meaning of the word. 
Can anyone help me  here.

Comment: show code and full error message.

Answer (score 1):

you could try install module "pip install pinyin", then print it out by:

```
print pinyin.get('你好', format="strip", delimiter=" ")
ni hao
```

Comment: I have tried installing pinyin but when I use pinyin.get it says invalid syntax. I have also restarted my kernel but no luck.

Comment: well I was able to install but pinyin.get('爱派尔') is giving output 'àipàiěr', actually tis is Apple

Comment: @YashishKarkera I you get  `invalid syntax` error. Just try `print(pinyin.get('你好', format="strip", delimiter=" "))` , that worked for me.